# JavaFX Capture Screen without ImageView in it

Tags: java, javafx, awt

I'm trying to take a screenshot with Robot and view it in an ImageView, The problem is the screenshot coordinates is the ImageView Global coordinates.

So basically I'm trying to capture what's behind the Imageview but instead I get a picture of the Imageview itself.

I can't minimize because I'm taking several continuous screenshots that may vary in resolution.

What can I do?

Comment: On solution making https://sourceforge.net/projects/xr3capture/ is to use one `Undecorated Stage` with a `Transparent Scene` and a `Transparent BorderPane` which contains a canvas with opacity `0.001` , but of course that might not be the only solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the response :), I might need help doing so.